# Chrome UI wouldn't display in selenium test

Tags: ubuntu, chrome, selenium

The issue is when I try to run a test with selenium in linux, the chrome ui does not appear, although I can see signs that the browser is active like the location where the browser should be getting getting laggy and my code reaching its checkpoints successfully. Only issue is I never see chrome ui. This only happens in ubuntu, the code runs fine on windows and mac.

Also, headless chrome is not active.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: To be honest I've no idea what's going on.

Comment: Selenium test starts, chrome window is not visible. Code still works and completes its task, only the chrome window is not visible.

Comment: How does it start? You're omitting all the details. It doesn't start here. I need to run Chrome, click the address bar, type a URL, hit enter. Your question must contain enough info to replicate or understand your issue from start to finish.

Comment: Selenium starts the browser. When selenium starts chrome, the browser window should be displayed but instead I get no visible window. The code runs fine and completes its test accordingly, meaning the selenium browser is running but the window is simply not displaying.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: Now I get it, Selenium is https://www.selenium.dev/ Have you tried asking in the official support group? http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users People there seem to know the subject. Selenium is not something a lot of people even known about. This question could be even more pertinent for stackoverflow.com where programmers and web developers hang out. The question is certainly about Linux/UNIX but it's way too specific.

Comment: Thank you.....Artem S. Tashkinov

Comment: hi 8bitdefault did you solve it? I have same issue